# Extra line in output when printing

Tags: python, printing

I am trying to get an output that looks like this:

```
'a',
'abandon',
'ability',
'able',
```

These lines should look like a list, I'm new and didn't know what to do XD

what I am getting

```
'a
','abandon
','ability
','able
```

here is my code:

```
`f = open("he.txt", "r")
for i in range(0,3000):
    print(f.readline(),"',", sep="", end='')
close()`
```

also, is there any way I can write this to a file? I have been looking for a way and couldn't find one, it interferes with reading the file.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
(1) you get *one* question per post, not multiples.  (2) You have to clearly define your problem.  Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  (3) Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  Asking us how to write to a file is misplaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A newline is included at the end of every line in a file. To get around this, you can use `rstrip` to strip a character at the end of a string. For example:

```py
f = open("he.txt", "r")
for i in range(0,3000):
    line = f.readline()
    line = line.rstrip("\n") # strip trailing newline
    print(line, "',")
close()
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the content of f(Can you paste it?)?
Also, it's best practice using context manager when reading from files, right now you are not checking for failure when opening the file.
Use `with` statement, e.g - `with open("he.txt", "r") as in_file: ...` and the file will be closed when you leave the context without manually taking care of it.

Answer (score -1):

You can change your code like this:

```
f = open("he.txt", "r") for i in range(0,3000): print(f.readline().rstrip(),"',", sep="", end='') close()
```

.rstrip() removes the whitespace at the end of the word

Comment: thanks that worked, but I want it in a list format. so that every line is like 'word',

Comment: This is StackOverflow, not CodeGolf. Please take the time to write your code in a legible manner, and avoid large single-line solutions.